# Google Maps Simulating Random Movement

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am planning to building an application to simulate movement on **Google map** however I am not seeing any examples of what I want. The movement I want to get is movement along random paths basically I want to move the pin forward from a particular predefined point without breaks or skipping points then after some time lets say after 10 mins of moving in one direction turn left or right, stop, forward or backward and so on.

I do not want to use already defined paths. It doesn't matter if the movement goes off road, once the movement is happening in an order without breaks. I also want to be able to log the movement every 10 seconds. I am not sure which event listener will have to be registered to handle this or how this will be handled.

I would like to implements this using **jquery**. I am accepting any advice, examples and demos (*examples does not have to be in the form of code snippets. It can be a formula on how to modify longlat coordinates to simulate a path*). Basically if I know how to increment a longlat coordinate to make movement forward but I have no understanding of how to manipulate longlat coordinates.

**This is what I think:**

Find a way to increment the coordinates to move straight then modify the degrees to turn and then move again then turn and so on.

Comment: I have not tried any code i am trying to plan an approach so i am looking at advice or examples(demo). I want to be able to learn from what has already been created in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have a noce tool called Google Playground,
You can check this animation sample using Google Maps Api V3

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#animate_v3

Answer (score 1):

Start with [`the docs`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays). Go there and search for "animating symbols" (can't link to that section directly). As for changing direction, depending on how far your markers are moving you may want the Haversine formula, found at [movable-type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did some code to simulate North/South and East/West

```
public static double eastMove(double d, double lat) {

    System.out.println("old North no longitude " + "," + lat);
    double newLatitude;
    double coef = d * 0.0000089;


    newLatitude = lat + coef;
    return newLatitude;
}


public static double northMove(double d, double lat, double lon) {

    System.out.println("old east" + lon + "," + lat);
    double newlongitude;

    double coef = d * 0.0000089;

    newlongitude = lon + coef / Math.cos(lat * 0.018);

    return newlongitude;
}
```

to use these two functions:

```
    newLongitude = northMove(15,Latitude,longitude);


    System.out.print("to North location");
    System.out.print(newLongitude );

    System.out.print(",");
    System.out.println(Latitude);




    newLatitude = eastMove(15,latitude);

    System.out.print("to East location");
    System.out.print(Longitude);

    System.out.print(",");
    System.out.println(newLatitude );
```